# Сгруппировать запрос правильно

Tags: mysql, sql

Требуется сгруппировать запрос sql по трем полям: ip, browser, user_id для статистики уникальных просмотров. Возможно ли вообще методами sql исключить группировку по user_id в случае если первые два совпали. Посколько неавторизованный пользователь с данными параметрами считается уникальным. Заранее спасибо, постарался максимально доходчиво донести мысль

Comment: Вы уж определитесь нужна ли вам группировка по трем полям или только по двум полям "ip, browser"

Comment: какое значения user_id у анонимных пользователей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
group by  ip, browser, case when ip <> browser then user_id end
```